# Post Multiple List of objects in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can i submit a form that contains 2 sets of Objects , My model looks like this

```
        public class Item 
    {

    public int Id{get;set;}
            public bool Selected{get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Price {get;set;}

    }

    public class Translations
    {

    public int Id{get;set;}
            public bool Selected{get;set;}
    public int ItemId{get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string TransName {get;set;}

    }

    public class ModelToSubmit
    {
    public List<Item> Items{get;set;}
    public List<Translations> TransItems{get;set;}
    }
```

How can i submit a ModelToSubmit to controller ? Any Idea? {Want to fetch all selected entries from Items and TransItems of ModelToSubmit

Comment: Here is how you can find out yourself: encoded in the format you plan to send it to the server, see in what format it comes in and send it in the same format.

Comment: You have to create 2 partial view. one of them for 'Item' and another one for 'Translation'. Based on count of your list,partial view will be rendered/called in your page. On submit it will automatically fill the 'ModelToSubmit' class and you will get updated value in controller.

Comment: Can you provide an example for it with some dummy data ? Since using Partial views can we submit data ?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is with EditorTemplates.  They take care of all the hard work for you.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8513087/61164

```
@model MVC3Stack.Models.ModelToSubmit

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index"))
{
    <table>
    Html.EditorFor(Model.Items);
    </table>
    <table>
    Html.EditorFor(Model.TransItems);
    </table>
    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

Create a folder in your Controllers View folder (or shared views) called EditorTemplates, and in that folder you create a razor file named after the type of your items.

Item.cshtml

```
@model Item

<tr>
    <td>@DisplayFor(x => x.Id)</td>
    <td>@EditorFor(x => x.Name)</td>
    <td>@EditorFor(x => x.Price)</td>
    <td>@CheckBoxFor(x => x.Selected)</td>
</tr>
```

Translations.cshtml

```
@model Translations

<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Id)</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ItemId)</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.TransName)</td>
    <td>@CheckBoxFor(x => x.Selected)</td>
</tr>
```

Submit Action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ModelToSubmit submitModel)
{
   return View(submitModel);
}
```

Comment: What happens if my model does not contain a single List<item>? How would EditorFor help in that case?

Comment: @Nilesh - My example has two List's.. so I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: My question is, what would happen if both the lists are empty? When I used `EditorFor` with both list empty, no controls are rendered. Not sure on this, may be I am doing something wrong!.

Comment: @Nilesh - Yes, of course nothing would be rendered... If you want something rendered, you should add a blank item.

Comment: That is exactly what I did in my answer. Added multiple blank items.

Comment: @Nilesh - not exactly.  You created multiple table rows with fields, not empty items in the list.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51221/discussion-between-nilesh-and-erik-funkenbusch)

Answer (score 2):

MVC uses the name attribute of html elements to bind view html controls to the model submitted to the controller, in case of lists the **name** attribute will be in the following format:

```
<input type='text' name='Items[0].Id'/>
<input type='text' name='Items[0].Name'/>
<input type='text' name='Items[0].Price'/>
.
.
.
<input type='text' name='Items[n].Id'/>
<input type='text' name='Items[n].Name'/>
<input type='text' name='Items[n].Price'/>
```

and for transItems

```
<input type='text' name='TransItems[0].Id'/>
<input type='text' name='TransItems[0].Name'/>
<input type='text' name='TransItems[0].Price'/>
.
.
.
<input type='text' name='TransItems[m].Id'/>
<input type='text' name='TransItems[m].Name'/>
<input type='text' name='TransItems[m].Price'/>
```

so you need to be sure that your html controls related to Items and TransItems have that format for the name attribute.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are aware of MVC ModelBinding and Stringly Typed Views, if not then get familiar with those first.

MVC Modelbinding uses the name attribute of html tag to match it with the corresponding Entity property.

Modifying your Entity a bit for better understanding

**ENTITY**

```
public class ModelToSubmit
   {
    public string TestProp{get; set;}
    public List<Item> Items{get;set;}
    public List<Translations> TransItems{get;set;}
   }
```

**VIEW**

```
@model MVC3Stack.Models.ModelToSubmit

@using (Html.BeginForm("PostToActionName","PostToControllerName"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TestProp)
    @Html.TextBox("Items[0].ItemPropName")
    @Html.TextBox("TransItems[0].TranslationsPropName")
    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
}
```

**ACTION**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostToActionName(ModelToSubmit collection)
{
   return View();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is your main view

```
@model MVC3Stack.Models.ModelToSubmit
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index1","Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    Html.RenderPartial("ItemsPartial", Model.Items);
    Html.RenderPartial("TranslationPartial", Model.TransItems);
    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
}
```

Items Partial View

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<table>
    @for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Name:</span>@Html.TextBox("Items[" + i + "].Name")
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>Price</span>@Html.TextBox("Items[" + i + "].Price")
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>Selected</span>@Html.CheckBox("Items[" + i + "].Selected")
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Translation Partial view

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<table>
    @for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Name</span> @Html.TextBox("TransItems[" + i + "].Name")
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>Trans Name</span> @Html.TextBox("TransItems[" + i + "].TransName")
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>Selected</span>@Html.CheckBox("TransItems[" + i + "].Selected")
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Post action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index1(ModelToSubmit submitModel)
{
   return Json("Index Success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Sample output

[image: Sample output]

And the data received in the action method
[image]

Comment: EditorTemplates do most of this work for you...  It's what they're designed for.